# Не создается бин в Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

При запуске приложения выскакивает куча ошибок, если определить некие параметры в одном класе для работы другого класса. Вот первый контроллер который должен использовать данные из другого класса:

```java
package hello;

import com.restfb.Connection;
import com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient;
import com.restfb.FacebookClient;
import com.restfb.Version;
import com.restfb.types.Event;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Facebook;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import javax.inject.Inject;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {

        private Facebook facebook;

        AccessTokenController accessTokenController;


        //FacebookClient.AccessToken accessToken = new DefaultFacebookClient(Version.VERSION_2_2).obtainAppAccessToken(accessTokenController.getAppId(), accessTokenController.getAppSecret() );
        FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessTokenController.getAccess(), accessTokenController.getAppSecret(), Version.VERSION_2_2);

        @Inject
        public HelloController(Facebook facebook) {
                this.facebook = facebook;
        }

        @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET)
        public String helloFacebook(Model model) {
                if (!facebook.isAuthorized()) {
                        return "redirect:/connect/facebook";
                }




                /*model.addAttribute(facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile());
                PagedList<Post> homeFeed = facebook.feedOperations().getHomeFeed();
                model.addAttribute("feed", homeFeed);*/

                Connection<Event> events = facebookClient.fetchConnection("closerkiev/events", Event.class);
                model.addAttribute("event", events);




        /*model.addAttribute(facebook.groupOperations().getGroup("closerkiev"));
        PagedList<Post> groupEvent = facebook.feedOperations().getFeed("closerkiev");
        model.addAttribute("feed", groupEvent);*/

        //model.addAttribute(facebook.eventOperations().getEvent("1635141143384681"));

        /*String event = facebook.eventOperations().getEvent("1635141143384681").getDescription();
        model.addAttribute("event", event);*/
        /*String query = "SELECT eid, name FROM event WHERE creator=closerkiev";
        List<FqlEvent> event = facebookClient.executeFqlQuery(query, FqlEvent.class);
        model.addAttribute("event", event);*/





                return "hello";

        }
}
```

Вот второй класс, который генерирует данные

```java
package hello;


import com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient;
import com.restfb.FacebookClient;
import com.restfb.Version;


public class AccessTokenController {

    private String AppId = "мой апп айди";
    private String AppSecret = "мой апп сикрет";

    FacebookClient.AccessToken accessToken = new DefaultFacebookClient(Version.VERSION_2_2).obtainAppAccessToken(AppId, AppSecret);

    private String access = accessToken.getAccessToken();

    public String getAccess() {
        return access;
    }

    public String getAppSecret() {
        return AppSecret;
    }

   // public String getAppId() {
   //     return AppId;
   // }
}
```

и класс запуска приложения:

```java
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

После запуска выкидывает кучу эксепшенов:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'helloController' defined in file
>   [D:\java\FBLogin\target\classes\hello\HelloController.class]: Bean
>   instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [hello.HelloController]: Constructor threw exception;
>   nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:275)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
>     at hello.Application.main(Application.java:14)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
>   Failed to instantiate [hello.HelloController]: Constructor threw
>   exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:267)
>     ... 22 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   hello.HelloController.(HelloController.java:29)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
>     ... 24 more

По моим подозрениям во всемвиноват первый эксепшн:

> Error creating bean with name 'helloController'

Как с этим бороться? Или точнее будет поставить вопрос где я туплю?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Из всего стэктрейса важны такие строки:

> Error creating bean with name 'helloController' defined in file [D:\java\FBLogin\target\classes\hello\HelloController.class]

Не удалось создать экземпляр класса `HelloController`. Почему?

> Constructor threw exception;

Было брошено исключение в конструкторе. Это плохо. Что же случилось?

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at hello.HelloController.(HelloController.java:29)

Возникло исключение `NullPointerException` в классе `HelloController` в строке 29. То есть в 29й строке происходит обращение к объекту, который еще не был создан.

В самом конструкторе только присвоение. Зато в инициализацию объекта входит эта строка:

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessTokenController.getAccess(), accessTokenController.getAppSecret(), Version.VERSION_2_2);
```

Тут вы вызываете метод `getAccess()` на объекте `accessTokenController`, который не создали. Вероятно, вы хотели повесить `@Autowired` на `AccessTokenController accessTokenController`.

А чтобы спринг вам его создал на самом классе `AccessTokenController` поставить аннотацию `@Component`.

---

Небольшое дополнение. Дергать методы в конструкторе при использовании спринга - **плохой** подход, т.к. на  момент создания одного бина, другие могут еще не существовать.

Сделайте в классе `HelloController` инициализирующий метод:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessTokenController.getAccess(), accessTokenController.getAppSecret(), Version.VERSION_2_2);
}
```

Он будет вызван гарантированно после того, как все необходимые бины созданы. И уберите создание `facebookClient` вне этого метода, оставив просто:

```
private FacebookClient facebookClient;
```

Comment: Да я попробовал но ошибка, к сожалению, не ушла.

Comment: Он почему-то не хочет создавать объект класса AccessTokenController

Comment: `@Component` на него повесили в самом файле AccessTokenController.java?

Comment: Да. Пытался повесить @Controller. Так как пишут, что создается при инициализации приложения, но ошибка та же

Comment: @AndrewKolenteew, обновил ответ.

Comment: Не тоже не работает но ошибка другая:  Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'helloController': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу

Comment: Исправил. Теперь новая версия ошибки

Comment: Вы забыли `@Autowired` на `AccessTokenController accessTokenController;`

Comment: Да, точно. Теперь все работает. Большое спасибо!

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23808/discussion-between-andrew-kolenteew-and-nofate).